Why doesn't `%python` or `$python` work on the macOS terminal?
I have worked with python through Jupyter Notebook. However, now I am trying to use Python on my Mac terminal. This is my first time using terminal, and it gives me the same output all the time:
Last login: Sat Sep 14 20:20:48 on ttys000
naomipluma@Naomis-MacBook-Air-6 ~ % 
naomipluma@Naomis-MacBook-Air-6 ~ % 
naomipluma@Naomis-MacBook-Air-6 ~ % 
naomipluma@Naomis-MacBook-Air-6 ~ % 
naomipluma@Naomis-MacBook-Air-6 ~ % ~ %python
zsh: permission denied: /Users/naomipluma
naomipluma@Naomis-MacBook-Air-6 ~ % $python

I don't understand how I can give myself access to the terminal. I am using my account which is the owner of everything. I have tried to look for help online but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be great!
I looked online and it told me to upgrade to the latest version and I do have it. I did download the latest version of python too for Mac users.

What exact command are you typing?  Is it python or %python or $python or something else?

In mac latest version Python is no longer builtin you need to download xcode. Or install python and set it's path, however this might not work with installing libraries in future, so it's better you get Xcode

how I can give myself access to the terminal. : What do you mean with this? You have obviously typed lines into the terminal, so you do have access.  What I do not understand, is, what you want to achive with the commands you have entered.

In the first command it looks like you typed ~ %python. The shell is going to take the first space-separated input as the program to run, with the rest as arguments to that program. In this case the program is simply ~ which expands to the path to your home directory; since that’s not executable, you get an error.
In the second command, you typed $python, which accesses the shell environment variable named $python. Since there is likely no such variable, this will expand to an empty string, and therefore the command ends up being empty (i.e. it does nothing).
The correct command to input is either  python or python3 depending on how it has been installed. Note that the initial % and $ characters you see in typical examples online are usually part of the shell prompt, and not part of what you need to type in.

Python is no longer builtin in Mac latest version, Download Xcode or try python3

This may be true, but how does this relate to the OPs problem?
